# How to convert Image into byte[] in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I want to save image in sqlite. In this method I have got image path into string.
My Question is How to convert it into byte[] format.

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
// we need to update the gallery by starting MediaSanner service.
mScanner = new MediaScannerConnection(ImagePreviewActivity.this,new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient() {

                        public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                                mScanner.scanFile(imageUri.getPath(), null );
                        }           

                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            mScanner.disconnect();
                            if (path.equals(imageUri.getPath())) {
                                 photoPath=imageUri.getPath();
                                        ImagePreviewActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            capture_photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.caturePhoto);
                                            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
                                            capture_photo.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

                                    }
                                });
                                mScanner.disconnect();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    mScanner.connect();
```

Comment: this can hep you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831151/how-to-store-and-retrieve-images-in-android-sqlite-database-and-display-them-on

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert image to byte array and viceversa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805146/convert-image-to-byte-array-and-viceversa)

Comment: I would just store the compressed image data directly from the file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java - not the decoded pixel data since that a) saves space b) is simpler to load as `Bitmap` (via `BitmapFactory`), i.e. dump file you get via `photoPath` into the database without decoding it.

Answer (score 9):

First convert ImagePath to Bitmap

```
       Bitmap src=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
```

Convert bitmap into byte array using this code:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        src.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        data = baos.toByteArray();
```

**After your question in comment**

To show byte array into imageview use these lines of code:

```
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

To show imagePath into imageView you can use

```
                 Bitmap src=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
                 imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you tell me how Convert byte array into bitmap and then convert Bitmap to Image

Comment: you can directly save byte array into image

Comment: Actually I want to fetch Image from Sqlite and show it in imageview. So, In what method we have to use for it

Comment: thanks again, but my main problem is I want to read from sqlite"while(cursor.moveToNext()){
   cimages.add(new CImage((cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(CAMERA_PHOTO)))));
  } how can use method to read it from sqlite ?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

this function convert an image into array byte[]:

```
 public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```